# 2019 MacBook Pro not charging after battery replacement (charged once)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I have a 13” 2019 MacBook Pro. The battery needed to be replaced so I ordered a non-OEM battery and swapped myself. Everything went smooth, no issues whatsoever. I reattached the bottom case and plugged it in. The battery was at 45% and it began charging. It charged to 100% and I turned it off.

The next time I turned it on a day or so later, it was showed to be reading all of the battery info in the system report. Shows a single power cycle, shows the battery type, the serial number, etc. But it will no longer charge! I have tried to reset the SMC, took the case back off and checked all of the ribbons and cabling, etc. the battery is obviously working because the computer is working and receiving power from the battery. When I plug the AC adapter in, the system report shows that the computer is being powered via the battery, not the adapter, and it doesn’t seem to be registering that the ac adapter is connected at all.

Has anyone run into this issue? I am stumped and super bummed out / unsure what to do. Especially being that it charged once perfectly. It
doesn’t show ‘not charging’ it’s just not detecting the adapter at all. Have also tried a different cable, different adapter, different wall socket. AC adapter works fine on different MacBook. I also just ran the diagnostics and it’s showing ‘no problems found’.

Comment: Have you tried plugging the cable into a different port?

Comment: I had an issue with the battery not charging that turned out to be a bad cable from the brick to the Mac. The cable looked fine, but failed. I'd try different cables/bricks before I'd go deeper.

Comment: Really you need to take it to a Repair shop. It needs a hands-on inspection. Either it's a crummy battery (and third-party ones are a lottery); or there's some problem with the Power Management Unit. Whether that was the original problem, or something as a result of opening it up: who knows.